# Need help in like button in my web app by Codeigniter using ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I have been working in app that contains a like button in profiles
I have stopped here and don't know how to complete it!!
What is missed here to make it work?
can you help ?

**Ajax**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#likebtn").click(function(e){

$.post(

     function(data) 
     {

     if (data.st == 0)
     {
     $('#likedata').html(data.msg);
     }
           else if (data.st == 1)
     {
         <?php echo $numlikes+1; ?>
     }
     }, 
     'json'
   );
 return false;   
 });


});

</script>
```

**Button in the View**

```
  <p> <input type="button" id="likebtn" class="btn btn-default btn-lg"> Likes</p>
  <span class="label label-default" id="Likes"><?php echo $numlikes; ?></span>
  <div id="likedata"></div>
```

**on construct function of the controller**

```
 function __construct() {
    parent::__construct();
                $prifile_id = $this->uri->segment(2, 9);
                $user_id = ($this->session->userdata['logged_in']['user_id']);

 }
```

**Controller function to add like**

```
 public function addlike()
    {
        $checklike = $this->$this->profiles_model->checklike($user_id,$profile_id);
        if ($checklike == FALSE)
        {
        $this->profiles_model->addlike($user_id,$prifile_id);
        $output= array('st'=>1);
     echo json_encode($output);
        }
        else {

             $output = array('st'=>0, 'msg' => "you already likes this profile");

         echo json_encode($output);
        }
    }
```

**Thanks in advance :)**

Comment: No `url` part for post ajax !!! ?

Comment: @jagad89 wher to put the url ?
the url is 
site_url/profiles/addlike
where addlike is a function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to increment count, but it is good to get updated count from server. 
Following is some javascript changes.

```
 <script>  
   $.post(
     "<?php echo site_url('profiles/addlike'); ?>",
     function(data) 
     {

     if (data.st == 0)
     {
     $('#likedata').html(data.msg);
     }
           else if (data.st == 1)
     {
         $("#Likes").text(st.numLikes);
     }
     }, 
     'json'
   );
 return false;   
 });


});

</script>
```

Now, Return updated numofLikes from server too.

```
public function addlike()
    {
        $checklike = $this->$this->profiles_model->checklike($user_id,$profile_id);
        if ($checklike == FALSE)
        {
        // Update this model method, so that it returns updated like count.
        $numLikes = $this->profiles_model->addlike($user_id,$prifile_id);
        $output= array('st'=>1,'numLikes'=>$numLikes);
     echo json_encode($output);
        }
        else {

             $output = array('st'=>0, 'msg' => "you already likes this profile");

         echo json_encode($output);
        }
    }
```